# Need to connect to Paypal APi

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Simple question

If you guys could tell me the requirements for PAYPAL API's to do credit card transaction and recurring payment via paypal API ?

If any body has a working example of the code, that would be gr8.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a PayPal Business account that supports this, and you would need to sign up for the services.  You can find information on getting started, code samples, and SDK available on [PayPal's Developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/).

Answer (score 0):

java code samples: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-java

Check in github if you are using any other language.